# Python : Display image from http response with image content type image/png

Tags: python, python-3.x, png, content-type

Can someone help me to display the json response coming in below format ( content type is image/png) using python 3.8

Now when the content type is image, I get the image's data in response, which is not base64 encoded. I need to show the image in a regular

Below is the response I am seeing.

I was able to show the image successfully using python 2.7 the below code. But I am not able to do the same using python 3.8

```
im = Image.open(StringIO.StringIO(response.content))
im.show()
```

```html
     �PNG

IHDR D     S���  � IDATx��� �T՝?�v5n�'F0&����s��d9�LB��'�L\����0Q #!.��D��01*�&$j4�mt�B"�"�(�
�Ⱦ�l���}�j��^�议����{��{�u�����}�ފ
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    h���G���jRmW��K���h���T{?՞K�o��      ��B8jɒ%�fΜ�oҤI���J�M�81L�2e����W���������NV(R[�a�=���~      ��0eʔ)aɒ%a���a׮]Z ��Y,Z�(<����ʡX��ϖ�~���^+�P
"v|�3���8�����+ä7ֆ��x=S���'��&���nR���KB�Ν��h,a?�(ݻw��t�I��G����      ��ؔ�X�v����o��������[?P��hPSSf��"���/>�[�n+�A4�ލ�
�
      ���uۚ��3��x[!Y "M"�g�Э[�q�����0z��0mڴ�`���f͚�nݺ�z��d��_L���ӧ�`Dee�ª���z      (�|�@���7� D�e�]�a����w�ygX�|y�G���Q�B����#�/���o�a      ��""
M B �Tđ�u�%;�0hР��u�Q$F�Q7�/�z}�2      P$�&!Q*�u�";�p�}���{����Ӹ��j�".��o�i      ""
D4g����{��3ۛ����!�_�vm��w�N<�Ĥ�~�d]sCu�^�#e�}<�Dzκ����e�hp�K�ۓ޾nݺ�"�Ν��>��C     @3�S,��hX�@�׾���{�ᇇ/��aȐ!a�ƍ��_~y���'�ӦMKn��_���q��x�X,�.��uq[��9rdعsg�.��X4����x�\�_�s
6d���z(     ��C�Ik���������])�!��#�H�nժUULΞ2cҤI9M���ئ
�-��Z��˾��[���Rц��N9�d�K/��%������>*Z(Q�Ǻ�{�-�z������Y     @ �E������*++?H���_!�~Tغuk&�p�Yge����3Y׷o�zGY8����˖-k�5Ǝ������9,^�8i�5⺸����\���M���V
N8�p�熹s�f��a䯺��}, 0T�)�:4���F
�1�G��Sd�og�!*<���[�3�rH�ir}9�g�"���4����]�շ��]�6 @���u��=Yג��1cƄN�:0=Hz�<N:����{�K ��}/��-�}ѢEEDL�81��.�C     ������5�Hk�)3��D4����Њ��r ��}/�~E�~�ƍ+Z bĈ�����P      %D ��i�&!Q��L B �X�^UU�o�A�[o��(a��{��+��"��޽{�
�V�
q:�Ν;'E����
:��B2�Fc�SN9%Y��K/�-[�49%A�o�o޼���̜93\t�E�)3>��� DH�"���/&���ɓ�2#N���G�˫V���u��x����eC��
qt
     @ �(_��8���äI��֭[3���:+����O�-[���Y��w�q@����t��1Y7cƌ0r��������O>���EE����J �駟�rH~x�����ŋ�}/���W�����3Y��.ĀN��i��"
>&�G�8�����'��)�@D:ѥK�dT���S[�����u����8��UW]>���%#A�����D^ee��:#9�[o�5,Y�$� ���������
�(_�V���8m�g>�p�qǅ��zK ��"��={����f5lȷ-�����Y�
     @#Q�""
L���      P!       �!       �D        eG        (;       @��        ʎ@       Pv"       ��#       �       �D        eG        (;       @��     �6�����ү_�m]�t�סC�x�_�4M��|;������=�:u���D     @�|��s�9�&�6m
 Pb���3τΝ;���>z�^�| D     @ֻw�_|�� ekϞ=���DM������D     @v�駇��竖P�y�=�no���D     @ۦJ@ً�g���}�}�!   P`o��v�~��m�ҥ˾:ċ1��i��w�q�_�N�:��+�* ���sș@   @-_����sN��� �o5��ot>��3�s���裏^�whq�Z�j�;��"(2   ��ݻ�΋/�ؕK��={��O|�5���o�-*�B}l�{l���fΜ����"*������J8��3ÑG�����}�@ ��    (��O?=̟?ߕK��y�=���Z=D�:�B��q�۱�j�@D �J�=|�_H��0ʺu�����} 
�7mٲe����rHN�R��-n�;wn�۷m�����},�i7n��o�N<�Ĥ���#Y�����@ �r!   PX�Z(f�L_SQ\pAf{Ϟ=�uO?�tx�嗓���/��h� ��׿�u&�P�~�=o�>}��c�&��<�L����
�CP."    
�CP."    
n_�ti8��3<F���SN9%�_�1�k_�Zx�7��}���~8~�5�7���r!   PX9_܋������/����/�i��q��%E��}����>~��}?��O7X�h�)3r�fj�m:�P�ȑ#���S�9F�u�7Yp�7c+�(����'��]��y�d9��z��,?�����_>`����r���0{���v,�57���Խo0��|0�����{{S�\�3(|_ �!hO"    
"�[��h�C��cE"[�<d��lo��Zaxv3J�� ��    �����3gf
��?�|�nʔ)�uӦM�u��N:)Y?gΜp��w7YH?����U�Vt "�)32t��d{UUUf]���mQz:���GL'Q��P�5'O��,Ǒ'�ϸ��~�믿���
���������JOm�~��u�����KR��L}�b�q�+s����   �\�Z(f�k���+�̙3äI��s�=��@�8qb�:ujX�j��C@�� D�zF��/�����[z���usBCُ4步O�H/�~%��㹭��{�j�]������_+����}�o_]G�Ho��/[g4������   �\�Z(f�kڸ�K��)S��%K���۷�]�vi%��g�hѢ����E��W>���~޻�����rE�Q/V�ץv�o�j�T;���ó?���m���f������� ����7��'��'��g�H���}���/{+�7�m�h�}7����    ��\�P��״qq��+W
!�h{��7��
�O�����1`��VwZ��3s����   ��Z(f�kڸ8=Cuu��A �?#�9ԕO    ���j�L�l7g;��kJ!!xP�M �C@}"    
�U�f0g�9�Q�@_��k6n׍y-i�~C pAD    ����`�vs�������;w�
�~�Y~�͵�@D��^�n�y���9�H h���Z�dɲ�3g�3rii�\:eʔ��Ǐ��� p2�9-�ݕ����n�v3�הj "�!ziY�ؼ0~��a�k��O�� D��q��9��M����ٷ�B�Z�@�k��k�ͱ0�ȥ%=r�>ס���d�ɨ"�o�j
�6��`!�3#��Ϡ�'�$& h���q2�dT����lW�B1}�@��?��0ġ��v�;�f�"&��"v�n�}����SF<1'����I� �ҁ�[~�R�������ۓ�%b�!N�G~��g�\1���^
�6�����K�gP���������ɨ�"U� D��]
����p�uׅ�z( F,X� �Y�&�[�.�^�:Y~���<������[oM
���xv^����Y���4���8=�;k�6��Ͻ�b�Seğq
r?3r��J��d�$'�����ɨ�@�@�@��������N1C_ӈ��ׇ�o�=\~��a̘1I�/���?�x�ٳg����T0��o ���^p��s�/a�?�G�C��H�ݎ;��C� Ýw��/_��s���5*t�޽�s���#̙3��9-��/<1{Y µA�]l���ȥ�3(�N�0IN@�:�D��@��
�w��`؈#j=oUUU?~�?�
�D&�����O NF��h^ʜ�
P�(.�K�(~6�ۦ��rK2�w���;��N2Tw�����m��^1C_Ӡ|0\{��Ix��T5w�uW�իW2rD[���fb���MC�Q��B�<xp�0ĸq�
�6X����H�g��985�O��N�o�+����"���6mZrA|Ȑ!a���Ia�?�A��k��>n�={vY"�ٮ U��R[.M�>=9�o�֝���ZŌ���L�<9�Pa�lÇO���+m=��J-!�_?��?�r
Y�pa�ѣG�uG��p�밸6��`�ό\j?�����>���d��p2�x�H����ׇ�o�=��ؘ1c��C>����d���o��M#�ٮ U��R[)łM}��8�C,�4���
��~f�R�Y)�ڵ�QUUUqT�镕�KS�7�����T������I���+�7?bĈ�>|����w0`_�0�q9�6lؚ;Ｓ����a��J�$��ɸ��d��^�*S�NM����ͽ0M1/���o���]��ߴ-�Q�7��X7Ȑ�?bX�|y^��?jԨ� ��\��s��Q�hg���_=�+�>V��~)/�?*�0�'?������h�qB�իW�����{[�����k��?����aqmе��ό\j?+ݻw��t��stК����#n����3x��m3�-�ܲ�gϞ_� &���͜�;�#��:�+R5*�Ƃԫ��ڢ��d��w����R�R�R�j+a�REĀT,g��vРAy!���1bD�筪�
_|�s�-1mj�������|r�����0������:A�$98���p'��c��Q�{��z=�����k�M����]wݕ|��C
P
P�C�j�誫�����E�9���.��V(b֬Y)f�O�~Ĕ=?~h������o��������{����^������y�˃]���Cv�>��T;��~[����g��xm��}C��b�W���@DC�U}��B��_(����?d����=���82S�},Y�D�A �!K�aqmPsm0���ȥ��bH�'�+Ĵ�������:�<x`!�A�ի�C:A�$98���p'��c��Q�{��Z&O����*�m���Ia5~fZ����(��Q�������</��+W���r�Ӽ��3�Ō���e�����߈�{��z'<8�O����Y��������w��a�����o�z�p��w���7K1���&����ݻ�λ�[���ݻw�>}��HT��*��*אC��rE��y�x��]��Z,��<�>~��_I?�P bУo/��0��u-~|{qk5�Y��L���o-�w�䚾wM�w����up�ϵ?�]tm����f?+��.�����1
2
��%Qa�h�2x�`��0��G��mW
�_��+��oЩ!5ȵJ�1�ׄ߿��t_E�������ߴG�#�}MY(T|*��.S�LI�30|uMiS�#��D<W�&z�t�R���.�����Sh�T!Q��=��*/���ܢ�ھ�F�>���7�Cp,���y�W��v��о>T� �����7�Ĕ�>;�ȳ,��s���\m��$�
��5�r>��l�i�3��i��3v�V,�O찀m�� ��s�X��pW2ӦJ���Wyag߾}�$1rq~~��ڵkW�$L�S���31���9,�ذa���LE�v�^�Z�� T��!\'Q,ΡҮK��H�1�ɩ7R�' ���3*��Q���f�7���k�̜`���"AS`4�BN����Ҿ�8.��|,ǀ���
Ƽ��n��7��Y=��栌��4�����_���kʹ����n��%>/������v��k��W��B�
w���%⹪lZ�H�Te��*�����n���G�� B������BD�(%�t�=Ʈ;P0tn�+`�xѱ��q��6��3��7��1�(M Y�gFk���:O���\Qg�"���n١��>��H���-\8b��,Z�'vX�6HAA�9K�����2m��tT������t*� 7l�P��t�������k,�_�`<��h������;�4^S��TD�pQx49�DP2YQ�s)֜�ў�,��"2x'�r�$�9s�>��em��H �X֓X ���2�k�cp����Z�5��Ս���m˿w|��s�_�_~\������s�6�m�qVȁ~����}��ȹo߉;��Nߟ���T;]>\�3م6?�K�=/��܉�Pٱ��d�G�ж�W�ڵkg\�ƫ$#UYFh�{���~�� "\�.�TJ��?�J���(J!A���[k>T*�`������}f���}����7e��WU�&�SF#��@BZw�O�"l���h�
2�]IEv[)���A��C�
?���A

�r�><��û���t�T��|�����7�ِ,�Q��"��r�W�yS��!V1D<�Z����۷�7iҤ���
}�!C�d� b�1C�й�ʽ�(e��5AD�֭S�tY�|yR���9��%���?��y��wg� ��E{�*�D��#ETD�mb�h�F���oݺ5e���I}?������A

��N;AD����v���z��2�7n\�Z���w�DAD��I�Λ�D
VI�HX��w"��Y�]1��@wL�Et� <m�m��K�e���!r�ΝO� L'H�qr�+�J��p/1�����^� ;�AxT�q�!��uɖ�3P��(6��(��� ���=�QquRi�)�j�ѪQ}�d"Jsx�����C9Ͼ�D��
�%���#�D���\ʈ!*+�`b���=�Q�8E��s�>|��� "��e��+:��������(����7�tS�+g��@�B�ԩS�=c�s���:N�O>�$n"^}�U眱cǆV:4��V�>կ�K����S�:��M�xKy�e���?�Dth֬Y��E���m���k�N�ߞJ$�q�Ge�
���k�A�(�PN��FN�d��)�P;ݶmۈ�o�޽��F�F��9��˻��e�����Pʌ��� DdjĢtE�*r��|����'��q���lY����{�c�l���e[ݺu�t;,$�Y�8&�V��u��wg� B���J��k*�ej_���D��}�}�9u/����-Z���o�)�J� "�}��~��tK��� ]� /^�X��ù� Rh��y��R*W��i0~���E��j�mi�@1D<L����g0� "��h�T
��0��ƻ�;]J<ri�_�Wκ�������{ˉ��lذ!�)3$��*9�T�^�b�n���dJ�"Oh�W��������K�"D����Hz�dD��չ���ݟʶb߾}qY��3#5}M�<��3N�T�t����*A�ޫ-w�W7E�+nk߾}�(
ZQ:U�+V��x��ߢJ��G3�Y�QAD��^0
|Z�M�Z[�.a��o߮���s��� ��
�W��i0^�AxV�"J�$��0��"^&FY��3EωS�N*�>H�`�]qO�w�Rf��]���hD���O�_�~qDl۶���q����/+-�P�S��s?E�Ы����d"���]QQD$'Qx����"*�\���h*&��pޕi+pf�������߉>�
���+'���3�&�P�
pm���g(�Q�6m̭�����7�S�n����]y�����bR�'�c�����?��D$O���b�J�1���9���ms�O���ϕ��C����ҥ?c�\��d����8c�D����~u���1I,�5o����G%��s��Xo���*v������pч�7H���,Opm�x�%���۠�8Eu����j�r�Jǎ��3���J�"�z��1mj�ڂ4
���J�B\�j���/�Ѳ�-���������8l�A�/��+[���[U�����u��^��E�̳�Sտ����-&���=�6v�-{�H�~�~7���=���C��"?���n7��mϭW�oa�9`���('F&���Q���FD�s���J�'9=R�G}�"M� �4�wY��J�!��Ϛ5��?��/JD�(��R��Y��ӥ������z/GW<}��q�۾/�O�O���n�V��f�ԉ<�Wo]G��8т����E�F\i2b G1D�o�F�B祲������i+pf���� �R%B�)��v�t�5TI�\֩�5d�D���X/�:��3jԨP[��W"�D��n�6>�a�(��ի�5�k׮Z�^�j�w�n������m��&[����'�x��l��@�>{���ؿ����\�G9���_������-���uշ�Fe����J�I���}m��F�}�}�h_�ʾ%{������>�����2Ⱦ"{�l���n��2��2�n���LvM���ݞ�o~d����a��
�:��}�6��e��Ǘ��/d���V��5A;���Ѿn�e�lz�|i��mԖ]��Ev�}Om�_�^jϓm�����cA�� ���숶� ���t���=�}-�K����-R�r�D%0�찔�hn���;G./2b�#L*������fYœ�L������O�������b��X��w^_^J�h�<[A"�f�V�Z�tjԨ�W٥+��f� �䳗�iS���Q�K��H�b�%���qQp����y;h���TP�pԾ�������$vX�q�/p��L�e�eX�)�ϖ�r�KlQ�s���qmH�Gw���!a�&��jشi��5�ӤO>�������Fi�gK@��N�g5�N���J��]�IP���+@��fkRFh2�<8 [�m4��R��b�=v0(�8L�qR*����\�'F�D01ʒ���(��xN��uR��-Gc�Q��&MQ�û����ի���1i%kY�XW�긜�2\��s#�K��g[9�++�����;���ݧ��w�=����"��������g�^��˫�D;��BTDQ^N�Xs�WV�߫�����9sf���F�����kba��ɦ]�vN��d��:[m"*&�K�x/Wг�~�+�Kd;���ۮK�� ��l����<vǢ����sm�=��d�<�Q� ګNmW'$�H hӒh�p�^y0(*�� ��
µ}M)���W��Tv_R(�Jˑ\��QYʀ"��{�FS9q��I!r4�2/��*���d��4�Q�"�h�O�sIc|od�d�ڏ4�x
R��6�6hJn"�z���]����xӦ��;;�?�N��C����_��ј���kܰbŊr#0��x��j\������Q
��b���m���m�|�:�4Wy�cǎ9�ժU��j}o9�}�Q�cǎR��H%��'�x��
tս
```

Answer (score 0):

As written in documentation for the first parameter of the Image.open() method: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html

"The file object must implement read(), seek(), and tell() methods, and be opened in binary mode."

To follow this requirement try to use this code:

```
img_link = 'https://some-image-link.com/image.png'

import requests
from PIL import Image
import io

response = requests.get(img_link)
in_memory_file = io.BytesIO(response.content)
im = Image.open(in_memory_file)
im.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. But I am having that string in a variable not as an API response.  I am seeing the below error , Can you help ?



 in_memory_file = io.BytesIO(imgstring)

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'